# How to Change the Background colour of a table-column in html and css?

Tags: html, css, styling, css-tables, web-frontend

[How to Change the Background colour of a table-column in html and css? I know how to change row colour. But I just can't seem to do this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhSGC.png)

Comment: You could also style a [colgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:nth-child` pseudo  selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or with [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) (in your specific case of *first column*)

```css
td:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

In your specific case it's also doable with:

```css
td:first-child {
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved the day

Comment: @AnantaDevDatta glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You can target the first cell (td element) in each row and set the background to red:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>cell col1</td><td>cell col2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>cell col1</td><td>cell col2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>cell col1</td><td>cell col2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved the day too :D